# How to add slideshow plugin for CKEditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I want add slideshow plugin for [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) on Drupal 7. I've tried several ways but without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you need slideshow plugin in ckeditor. Could you explain briefly? There are separate modules available for slideshow.

Comment: i want shows content of the article with slideshow

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin by adding the plugin to: sites\all\modules\ckeditor\plugins

Once the plugin is unpacked correctly, it will automatically appear on the plugins list in your CKEditor profiles along with its toolbar buttons.

See [these](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Enterprise/Drupal_7/Plugins) instructions.

Comment: I have tried to do so but failed. It does not display icon slideshow in "editor appearance"

Answer (score 0):

> [I have tried to do so but failed. It does not display icon slideshow in "editor appearance"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166298/how-to-add-slideshow-plugin-for-ckeditor/173448#comment200559_166338) –  Lê Quang Tú

The problem is in the "editor.ui.addButton" in "plugin.js": No icon is defined.

```
// Create a toolbar button that executes the above command.
editor.ui.addButton( 'Slideshow', {
    // The text part of the button (if available) and tooptip.
    label: lang.insertSlideShow,
    command: 'slideshow',
    // The button placement in the toolbar (toolbar group name).
    toolbar: 'insert',
    icon: this.path + 'icons/slideshow.png'
});
```

You have to add `icon: this.path + 'icons/slideshow.png'`.